# How to do left to right transition and vice versa in viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iphone application, i am using storyboard layout to display my views. for my requirement , i am navigating my storyboard viewcontrollers with the help of this code:

```
 NextViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:NULL]
                                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextView"];

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Note that seques are not available in my code.  This current approach perfectly navigating the views from bottom to top. But i want to navigate from left to right/ viceversa. please provide any solution to resolve my problem.

Comment: Use a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use a *push* transition. *Push* requires that you have a `UINavigationController`.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

If you are using Storyboard, then create a `UINavigationController` and `Ctrl-drag` from it to your view controller and set it as the `rootViewController`. This will create the default-looking navigation bar at the top of your app.

To "go back" programmatically from a pushed view controller, use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I suggest you read about *modal* and *push* transitions, because the differences between them are not just "bottom-to-top" and "right-to-left". *Pushing* is for seeing more detail, while presenting a view controller *modally* is for starting a different task.

Comment: No its not working. it doesn't make sense to navigate my controller. For some purpose i intensionally left modal and push transistion.